# Quebrar um For Loop

Tags: delphi-7

Como faço pra quebrar um loop?
EX:

```
for x:=1 to 10 do
if x = 5 then "break"
end
```

Quando chegasse em 5, o loop seria quebrado, não continuaria mais.
Claro que seria outra condição.
Gostaria de saber se tem como.

Comment: O comando é "break" mesmo. É só tirar as aspas dele e transformá-lo num comando :-) `if x = 5 then break;`

Comment: Eu não downvotaria esta questão. Pior que isso não tá tão óbvio no Google procurando em português, pelo que vi agora. Eu até decidi transformar meu comment em resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comando para quebrar ou interromper um loop, em Delphi, é `break`.

Usando seu código como exemplo:

```
for x:=1 to 10 do
begin
    if x = 5 then
        Break;
end;
x = 5; // nesta linha, x de fato será 5.
```

Este comando pode ser usado para quebrar qualquer estrutura de loop, como `while` e `repeat`.

Um comando `break` quebra apenas o loop no qual está contido. Se um loop estiver contido em outro, o loop externo não será quebrado pelo comando `break` executado no loop interno.

Answer (score 4):

```
for x:=1 to 10 do
if x = 5 then break;
end
```